# Extreme value theorem examples

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let S be a nonempty subset of R.
(a) Give an example to show that, if S is not closed, then there is a continuous
real-valued function with domain S that does not attain a maximum value.
(b) Give an example to show that, if S is not bounded, then there is a continuous
real-valued function with domain S that does not attain a maximum value.
(c) Give an example of a continuous bounded function with domain R that attains
neither a maximum or minimum value.

a) $f(x)=x$ $x∈ (0,1)$

b) $f(x)= x/(1+x)$ $x∈[0, \infty)$

c) Would the same example in (a) work?

Comment: For c) a's answer is not bounded. You can use b, do an odd extension for x < 0.

Comment: Can the odd extension be -x/(1+x) ?

Comment: it is better written as $ - |x|/(1+|x|) for x < 0.